# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I do not want every time to initialize each field, I want all initsilizirovat in the constructor, it is possible to do?

```
 var districts = _districtRepository.FindBy(d => d.CityID == id).Select(d => new DistrictViewModel(d)).ToList();
```

models:

```
public class DistrictViewModel
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public DistrictViewModel()
    {

    }

    public DistrictViewModel(District district)
    {
        if (district != null)
        {
            ID = district.ID;
            Name = district.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
var districts = _districtRepository.FindBy(d => d.CityID == id)
                                   .AsEnumerable()
                                   .Select(d => new DistrictViewModel(d))
                                   .ToList();
```

In this case your statement .Select(d => new DistrictViewModel(d)) is linq-to-object statement, not linq-to-entity and it will work.

Comment: That should be `AsEnumerable()`. There is an `Observable.ToEnumerable` extension method, but that isn't the one to call.

Comment: I assume that IQueryable -> AsEnumerable doesn't impact performance - as an Enumerable is still only evaluated when being hit?
As when you'd use IQueryable -> ToList - which triggers execution immediatly? Am I correct?

Comment: AsEnumerablehas impact on performance, but it is not immediate. When you use AsEnumerable, all that is after it will be executed on client and will not be transferred to database query. But in this case performance hit is not so big. This query get whole row District but it really need the only two fields ID and Name.